# Javascript Event - Holding CTRL Key and mousover on button at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two solutions so far but none of them work. Can anyone lead me in the right direction ?

I am trying to achieve the folowing:

1. Hide text in a div
2. User will press Ctrl key, then put his mouse over a button - a javascript function has to be called, and the text in the div should be displayed
3. If the User releases the Ctrl key - the text should disappear (even if the mouse is on the button), similarly if the User moves the mouse out from the button - the text should disappear (even if the Ctrl key is pressed)

First try:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){

           $("#center").css("visibility","hidden"); //Hidden text in the beginning

            $("#select").mouseover(function(e){
                while(e.ctrlKey) 
                  $("#center").css("visibility","visible");
                $("#center").css("visibility","hidden");     
            }).mouseout(function(){
               $("#center").css("visibility","hidden");
            });
        });   
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
      <button type="button" id="select">CTRL+mouseover</button>
      <div id="center">
            <h1>Text text text</h1>
      </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

The second try:

http://jsfiddle.net/o0q5nszz/10/

As a resume, the idea of the entire code is that holding CTRL + mouseover on a **button** reveals a hidden text. Can anyone lead me in the right direction ?

Comment: your second try seems working what the problem?

Comment: Your jsfiddle seems to be working fine, I see no problem?

Comment: It doesn't have a button and I need this to happen when I am holding CTRL and mouveover on that button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a button and attached the previous #center mouse events on the   button

see this working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o0q5nszz/11/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).focus();
    var keyPressed = false;
    var mouseovered = false;
    $("#btn").mouseover(function(e){
      doStuff();
         mouseovered = true;
    });
    $("#btn").mouseout(function(){
        doStuff();
        mouseovered = false; 
    });
    $(document).keydown(function(e){
         doStuff();
         if (e.ctrlKey) 
         {
             keyPressed = true;
         }
        else keyPressed = false;
    });

    $(document).keyup(function(e){

         if (keyPressed) 
         {
             keyPressed = false;
         }
        doStuff();
    });

    function doStuff()
    {
        if(mouseovered && keyPressed) $("#center").css({"color": "#000"});
    else  $("#center").css({"color": "#fff"});
    }
});
```

Comment: That works smoothly though I have just one more question: would it be possible for that text not to be seen while I select that block of text?

I mean...that text to be triggered as just an accordion style when hovering and pressing CTRL so the text can't be selectable while the event is not triggered

Comment: @Alex: see this http://jsfiddle.net/o0q5nszz/12/, you would need to change css style to visibility hidden, and get the button out of the `#center` div

Answer (score 1):

You can do old way, but in 2019, you could do new way:

[MouseEvent.ctrlKey read-only property is a Boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/ctrlKey)

```
   <img onmouseover="bigImg(event)" onmouseout="normalImg(event)">


    function bigImg(event) {

             // false if no ctrl key, true, if pressed
              console.log(event.ctrlKey)


       }
```